# epydoc hide some class functions?

Tags: python, private, docstring, epydoc

I have some methods in my class which are only meant to be used by other methods of the class. I've prefixed their names with '_'. Can I hide those functions from epydoc? Is it a good idea?

Should I use '_' or double underscore? To be honest I didn't get the difference after reading about them in some places. Should this naming convention be used only on module/class (instance) functions? Or also variables?

Comment: Use single underscore by convention. Using it on other types of variable is accepted (as far as I know), although methods & functions are the most common uses.

Comment: ok, any ideas how to make them hidden to epydoc though?

Comment: Sorry, no. I haven't used epydoc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to hide all private methods and private variables, pass option '--no-private' to epydoc.

Note that - for epydoc - a method or variable is private if:

- its name starts with an underscore '_' **and**
- its name does not end with an underscore '_' **and**
- you did not include its name in the special **all** dictionary.

Alternatively you can use the 'undocumented' tag to force epydoc to completely ignore certain methods or variables.

For instance (and here I assume a ReStructured Text kind of formatting):

```
class MyClass:
  """Some neat description

  :undocumented: x
  """

  def _y(self): pass
  def x(self): pass
  def z(self): pass
```

will result in the documentation to contain only _y (unless you used the '--no-private' option) and z. There will be nothing about x even if it is not private.

Whether private methods should be visible at all or not in the final documentation is a matter of taste. To me, documentation is read by people who don't or should not have any interest in the internal implementation. Private methods are best hidden completely.

Comment: or `@undocumented: x` in epytext syntax.